# How to set up the matrix of a finite difference equation (Heat problem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

After doing the finite difference approximation of a 2D heat equation. How do we put this equation into a matrix to solve it? I want the actual steps of putting the numbers in the rows of the matrix because i don't find anything that explains this :((
1D equations are easy to implement but 2D equations seemed more tricky

[2D equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ADJ.png)